# Given component works but redirects to 404 page when "**" route is configured

Tags: angular, routes, custom-error-pages

**Description**
In an Angular 14 application, one of my pages/components works as expected if I don't set the "**" route in `app-routing.module` . But if I configure the "`**`" route in `app-routing.module` that page/component always directs to the 404 page.

**Code**

I have trimmed down and anonymised the application. (The application is almost empty now and the problem still happens.) :

- Stackblitz'* link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4uhljr
- GitHub link (not linked to the Stackblitz link):    https://github.com/TT10/Debug20220804

'* *(Please note that I have not been able to run anything on Stackblitz, it looks like compilation takes eternity. I had to recreate all the folders and them drop files in each of them manually so I can't guarantee that the Stackblitz code works. I am only using this to share code.)*

**Current structure**

/`AppModule/AppComponent` --> OK

//`StuffModule` --> OK

///`MainStuffComponent` --> OK

////`Component1A` --> OK

////`Component1B` --> OK

///`OtherStuffComponent` --> 404 page (if "`**`" route is configured)

**How to observe the "bug"**

To observe the bug, launch the application and click on the `Go to other stuff where 404 happens` link.

**Structure description**

At launch it should boot on the `main-stuff.component` in the `stuff.module`.
`main-stuff.components` itself is a holder for `component1A` and `component1B`.
`component1B` contains a link to component `other-stuff.component`.
Ideally I would have liked the `other-stuff.component` to be a child component of `main-stuff.component` too, but that didn't go well as I wanted it to use different route (a part of these are requirements and not my own choices).
The 404 redirection happens when going to `other-stuff.component` ( route: `otherStuff/:id`)

I'm also not 100% sure if I'm misusing nested components yet as this is all rather new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the created module as a lazy loaded module, that was the issue.

Before:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainStuffComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

After:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./stuff/stuff.module').then((m) => m.StuffModule),
  },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvr99j)

Comment: This is indeed solving the issue in the stripped application, but in the full application, it prevent Component1A  and Component1B from loading... any idea ? (<-- it actually works in the full applications too, I forgot than in the main code I had 2 commented lines).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The order of routes is important because the Router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes.

You could create new NotFoundModule and configure with parent module instead of adding inside parent routes config.

**app.routing-module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: MainStuffComponent }];
```

**not-found.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';

const COMPONENT = [NotFoundComponent];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...COMPONENT],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }]),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class NotFoundModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StuffModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NotFoundModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-btukgn?file=src/app/app.module.ts)**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I like the approach and I just tried it, but I still had to lazy-load `StuffModule` other wise the `otherStuff/:id` route works but then the `'' (blank route)`  renders a blank page with only the application title. (I see that things work in your Stackblitz link though.)

Comment: I just found the solution to the issue in my previous comment by completely removing the `'' (blank route)` from the `app-routing.module` and defining it only in `StuffModule`'s routing.

Comment: Did you add NotFoundModule at last item of import?

Comment: In `app.module`, yes, in last position of imports.

Comment: can you try to reproduce in this stackblitz?