# Maximum call stack size exceeded in Angular when importing a pipe to a child module

Tags: angular, module, pipe

I created a simple pipe for a string operation and I think it would make sense that it would be available everywhere in the application.

It is located in `src/pipes` folder.

To keep code anonymised I renamed stuff and the pipe is now called `SomePipe`.

It is declared in `app.module`, then it is imported in `child.module`.

But it causes "Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded".
I join the code of `app-routing.module` as well as I feel like it may have to do with this... (its current state where it is lazy-loading `child.module` is the result of another question I posted here because otherwise one of the child components of `child.module` which used a different route would re-direct to the 404 page **IF** the `**` route was set in `app-routing.module`, but would work fine it the `**` route was not set. This was the other question: [Given component works but redirects to 404 page when "**" route is configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73230166/)
Someone also suggested in it that I could create a distinct module for the `**` route and the 404 page, but I have tried this yet and I'm not sure if it would have anything to do with the current issue.)

**app.module.ts**

```
(...)

import { SomePipe } from './pipes/some.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    SomePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   ChildModule,
   HttpClientModule
],
  providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**child.module.ts**

```
(...)
import { SomePipe } from './pipes/some.pipe';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'stuff/:id', component: StuffComponent },
    { path: '', component: MainThingsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainThingsChildComponent1,
    MainThingsChildComponent2,
    StuffComponent,
    MainThingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      RouterModule.forChild(routes),
      SomePipe
    ],
    providers: [
        SomeService
    ]
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./things/child.module').then((m) => m.ChildModule)
    },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**some.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'somePipe'
})
export class SomePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(number : number): string {
      (...)
      return [some string];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post SomePipe code ?

Comment: Imports are for modules, you are importing somepipe into the modules of the child module

Comment: Rule of thumb: if a component/directive/pipe/etc is going to be used in more than one module it should then be in its own module.

Comment: You mean that I cannot declare a pipe at app level and pass it to children module ? And I should have a module for each pipe in such case ?

Comment: You could make a `PipesModule` and export all your pipes in it. then `import:[PipesModule]` in what ever modules need pipes

Comment: And to answer your question, no you can not import and supply to the children. You import for components within that module only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to share a component/directive/pipe/etc. between multiple modules, it is best to place it within a shared module. This will help avoid the error that you are receiving.

So what we can do is place all your pipes in a `PipesModule` (Note the `exports` property, this is what exposes module items to other modules):

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyPipe1, MyPipe2],
  exports: [MyPipe1, MyPipe2]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

Then the pipes module can be imported in whatever modules may need them. For example here in the app module:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, PipesModule]
  // Other settings in your app module
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And also here in your child module:

```js
// Note: BrowserModule can only be imported once, so we will import CommonModule here
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, PipesModule]
  // Other settings in your app module
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you! Though, there is small mistake in your answer, ( in @NgModule decorator ) it's "exports" with "s" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Move SomePipe from imports to declarations array

Comment: That will just give an error saying that `SomePipes` is declared in two modules.

Comment: Indeed that is something I already tried and this was causing an error because the pipe was declare in two modules.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn My answer was too concise, it is obvious that if he declared it in another module he simply has to import it otherwise he declares it in the module itself.